# Cordove File Plugin not working with Browser Platform

Tags: cordova, fileapi

I was trying to work with

```
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.2 "File"

org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.8 "File Transfer"
```

on *browser platform* (I am using chrome under fedora with options --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access)

but it seems that it's not working at all

1. there is no cordova.file variable
2. I was trying to debug (with the chrome debugger) the plugin (function `resolveLocalFileSystemURI`).
   `exec(success, fail, "File", "resolveLocalFileSystemURI", [uri]);` is called but `CommandProxyMap` is empty ***so nothing happen***

If someone has an example which is working or a tutorial to explain how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread has a bit of age to it now, but I wanted to update here in case anyone comes across it as I have...

While I can't say specifically when this was corrected/added, you can now use cordova.file from your browser (personally tested in Chrome) if you use the latest of file and file-transfer plugins as well as the 'browser' platform.

To get around the cordova.file is undefined issue present with previous releases of file, here is what I personally did (I am using Ionic, so sub 'cordova' as needed):

```
> ionic plugin remove org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
> ionic plugin remove org.apache.cordova.file
> ionic platform add browser
> ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git
> ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
> ionic run browser
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No, there is no *cordova.file*. It is platform specific object containing paths to certain locations. On browser you can just use the root directory.
2. You need to request quota first for browser. Below is example straight from my app.

Example:

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

if (isPhoneGapApp)
{
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess.bind(this), this.errorHandler);
}
else
{
    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onFileSystemSuccess.bind(this), this.errorHandler);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
    });
}
```

In case *LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT* is undefined, replace it with 1.